Text ellipsis overflowing width of component
I'm attempting to add a text ellipsis effect when the width of the screen reduces. I want the text ellipsis to happen and not push the components of the screen. This is how the component look on a normal screen device:

And this is what is happening for smaller screen sizes:

How I'm trying to make it look on smaller screens:

This is the component:
const MusicCard = ({
  music,
  className,
  checked,
  onClick,
  provider,
  canPlay
}) => {
  return (
    <div
      className={twMerge(
        `w-full p-4 ${checked ? 'bg-music-card' : 'bg-white'} rounded-md flex flex-row justify-between items-center cursor-pointer apple-shadow`,
        className
      )}
      onClick={onClick}
    >
      <div className="flex flex-1 flex-row items-center">
        {canPlay ? (
          <button
            className="p-0 w-8 h-8 min-w-[32px] mr-2 rounded-full text-white flex justify-center items-center mobile:mr-4"            
          >
            <PlaySVG style={{ width: 25 }} />
          </button>
        ) : null}

        <img
          id="image"
          className="w-[50px] h-[45px] z-2 mobile:w-[70px] mobile:h-[65px]"
          src={music.artworkURL}
        />
      
        <div className='flex-1 ml-2'>
          <span className='font-semibold' style={{
            whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
            overflow: 'hidden',
            textOverflow: 'ellipsis'
          }}>
            This is a long text message</span>
        </div>

        <div
          className={`w-[30px] h-[30px] flex ${checked ? 'border-none' : 'border-terciary'} border-1 items-center justify-center rounded-full ml-[30px]`}
        >
          {checked ? (
            <CheckIcon color={'#422D8F'} />
          ) : (
            <AddIcon className={"#120a31"} />
          )}
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  )
}

export default memo(MusicCard)



You'd want to override the implicit min-width: min-content on the <div> wrappers of the text that are direct children of any horizontal flex layout. For example, consider applying min-width: 0 via min-w-0 to allow this element to shrink smaller than the length of the text:
<div
  className={twMerge(
    `w-full p-4 ${checked ? 'bg-music-card' : 'bg-white'} rounded-md flex flex-row justify-between items-center cursor-pointer apple-shadow`,
    className
  )}
  onClick={onClick}
>
  <div className="flex flex-1 flex-row items-center min-w-0">
    …
    <div className='flex-1 ml-2 min-w-0'>
      <span className='font-semibold' style={{
        whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
        overflow: 'hidden',
        textOverflow: 'ellipsis'
      }}>
      This is a long text message</span>

Then, apply the truncate Tailwind class on this same <div> instead of the inner <span>:
<div className='flex-1 ml-2 min-w-0 truncate'>
  <span className='font-semibold'>
    This is a long text message
  </span>



const PlaySVG = () => 'PlaySVG';
const CheckIcon = () => 'CheckIcon';
const AddIcon = () => 'AddIcon';

const MusicCard = ({
  music,
  className,
  checked,
  onClick,
  provider,
  canPlay,
}) => {
  return (
    <div
      className={twMerge(
        `w-full p-4 ${checked ? 'bg-music-card' : 'bg-white'} rounded-md flex flex-row justify-between items-center cursor-pointer apple-shadow`,
        className
      )}
      onClick={onClick}
    >
      <div className="flex flex-1 flex-row items-center min-w-0">
        {canPlay ? (
          <button className="p-0 w-8 h-8 min-w-[32px] mr-2 rounded-full text-white flex justify-center items-center mobile:mr-4">
            <PlaySVG style={{ width: 25 }} />
          </button>
        ) : null}

        <img
          id="image"
          className="w-[50px] h-[45px] z-2 mobile:w-[70px] mobile:h-[65px]"
          src={music.artworkURL}
        />

        <div className="flex-1 ml-2 min-w-0 truncate">
          <span className="font-semibold">
            This is a long text message
          </span>
        </div>

        <div
          className={`w-[30px] h-[30px] flex ${checked ? 'border-none' : 'border-terciary'} border-1 items-center justify-center rounded-full ml-[30px]`}
        >
          {checked ? (
            <CheckIcon color={'#422D8F'} />
          ) : (
            <AddIcon className={'#120a31'} />
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app')).render(
  <React.Fragment>
    <MusicCard music={{ artworkURL: 'https://picsum.photos/50/45' }} />
    <div class="w-64">
      <MusicCard music={{ artworkURL: 'https://picsum.photos/50/45' }} />
    </div>
    <div class="w-48">
      <MusicCard music={{ artworkURL: 'https://picsum.photos/50/45' }} />
    </div>
  </React.Fragment>
);
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.3.1/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-QVs8Lo43F9lSuBykadDb0oSXDL/BbZ588urWVCRwSIoewQv/Ewg1f84mK3U790bZ0FfhFa1YSQUmIhG+pIRKeg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.3.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-6a1107rTlA4gYpgHAqbwLAtxmWipBdJFcq8y5S/aTge3Bp+VAklABm2LO+Kg51vOWR9JMZq1Ovjl5tpluNpTeQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script>window.exports = {};</script>
<script src="https://www.unpkg.com/tailwind-merge@2.3.0/dist/bundle-cjs.js" integrity="sha384-DiahyzS/YbKC+MesqkYzmlax937CdGiTsSHB57Li7iKxKYIOYYlJd0BsDIQnq2T1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.4"></script>

<div id="app"></div>



